# Push Notification sent from azure cloud service Via GCM is not reaching the device

Tags: android, azure, google-cloud-messaging

I'm pushing a notification from the azure, which in turn receiving a response from GCM as something like this,

```
{
  "multicast_id": 741482134591577979968,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "registration_id": "APA91bHUJE2EEEKkdjJaETiDfiaBiAxHdHB2q4moPhjknmklmXsJlx7PXjFZpJcPrQ2jXBCRgh8nvI24Fu2qP2UWcvc5phl_JZVBF7_aFm8zavy9_R8qOsf0y7KNYPIrWB-nVfVsRciBivkXkUPm3COpSrGzJafvghvuiou",
      "message_id": "0:1425296083478008%e8bbjbkkjdfdvc4f9fd7ecd"
    }
  ]
}
```

Eventhough we are getting success response,the message ain't reaching the device.

We have tested manually by sending messages from azure which is perfectly delivered.

We have tested by sending messages from `RESTCLient` which is also perfectly notified.

Please help us where does the message gets dropped in the flow.
Is there any way to check the path of **Azure--GCM--Device**.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

The registration id of the device might be changed. Check if the same registration id is present in the device while using `gcm.register(SENDER_ID);`